# My EDIT button is not working properly? (Javascript Todo List) Beginner

Tags: javascript, html, edit

I am a beginner in Javascript and is currently trying to make a todo list web app. But currently stucked at the edit button.

As you can see, I wanted to make an editable checklist but somehow everytime I hit the edit button, a new input comes out instead of replacing the current one. It also removes the 'checkbox' somehow.

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Thank you for your time!

Somehow the edit button doesn't work at all when I try to run it on VSCode. Here it works, but not as I wanted though.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('#invitedList');

ul.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    const button = event.target;
    const li = button.parentNode;
      if(button.textContent === 'edit') {
      const span = li.firstElementChild;
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'text';
      input.value = span.textContent;
      li.insertBefore(input, span);
      li.removeChild(span);
      button.textContent = 'save';
    } else if(button.textContent === 'save') {
      const input = li.firstElementChild;
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = input.value;
      li.insertBefore(span, input);
      li.removeChild(input);
      button.textContent = 'edit';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- TASK LIST THAT IS SUPPOSED TO BE EDITABLE GOES DOWN HERE, AS A TEMPLATE -->

<div id="taskit" class="task">
  <ul id="invitedList">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label>
      <span id="editable" class="custom-checkbox">Edit This</span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" id="editbtn">edit</button>
  </ul>
</div> 
          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `li.firstElementChild` is the `<input type="checkbox" />`. That's why it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying Node.ReplaceChild() instead of creating a new element? Not sure how to tell you exactly how to do it but here is a link to the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change styling instead of creating and removing elements. Here is possible solution:

```js
let isEditState = false;
const editButton = document.querySelector('#editbtn');

editButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const span = document.querySelector('#editable');
  const checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
  const text = document.querySelector('#text');
 
  if (isEditState) {
    span.innerText = text.value;
    checkbox.style.display = 'inline';
    text.style.display = 'none';
    editButton.innerText = 'edit';
  } else {
    checkbox.style.display = 'none';
    text.style.display = 'inline';
    editButton.innerText = 'save';
  }
  
  isEditState = !isEditState;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="taskit" class="task">
  <ul id="invitedList">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <input type="text" id="text" style="display: none"/>
    <label>
      <span id="editable" class="custom-checkbox">Edit This</span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" id="editbtn">edit</button>
  </ul>
</div> 
          
</body>
</html>
```